# Menubar hidden in all KDE apps

Tags: appmenu, kde-apps, kubuntu-netbook

I am using Kubuntu 10.10 with Plasma-Netbook on my netbook. Somehow I messed up with window's settings and now the menubar (the one on top of the window, just below the titlebar, which has the File button, Edit, Settings, Help, ...) is hidden from all my KDE applications.

I don't remember what I did to hide the menubar, I clicked somewhere in the context menu which shows right-clicking on window title, but I cannot find that setting anymore.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to get your menu bar back.

The menu would likely be "Setting" => "Show Menubar".
[image: Gwenview menu]

Comment: Thank you, I had already tried that shortcut but with no success. When I switch to Plasma-Desktop, Ctrl-M works and I get the menubar back, but when I come back to Plasma-Netbook the new apps I run are without menubar again and Ctrl-M does not work. If I open the menubar as a context menu with Alt-P, the "Show Menubar" in Settings is ticked. If I run an app in Plasma-Desktop with the menubar shown, then I switch to Plasma-Netbook the bar is still there; unfortunately if I close the app and run it again the bar is disappeared. Any suggestion?

Comment: I found out that the "context menu" I was talking about actually was the "Window Menubar" widget, placed on the topbar of Plasma-Netbook, next to the "Search and launch" button. This widget in my case completely replaces the menubar of KDE applications, I don't know if this is the correct behavior. Anyway I found Plasma-Netbook quite buggy and I left it for Plasma-Desktop.